# Generating ad report in facebook MARKETING API or GRAPH API. [PAGE_NAME field ]

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I am losing my mind. I have report in https://business.facebook.com under ad account.

I am using breakdown called Page name. It shows page of the ad in Excel column (I think you get idea). Problem is when I try to make my report using marketing API and I can't have `page_name` field in python SDK or via regular http requests. I can't find it in API docs. Is there really no way to include `page_name` in report via API? I have it using browser version of business.facebook.com. Good people of Stack Overflow please help. Facebook API sucks so much :/

```py
from facebook_business.api import FacebookAdsApi
from facebook_business.adobjects.adaccount import AdAccount
from pandas import DataFrame
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import Workbook

access_token = 'my access_token'
print(access_token)

FacebookAdsApi.init(app_id, app_secret, access_token)
breakdowns=['publisher_platform','platform_position']
params = {'time_range': {'since': '2022-12-01', 'until': '2022-12-25'},
          'time_increment':1,
          'level': 'ad',
          'sort': ['spend_descending'],
          'export_format':'xls'}
fields = ['adset_name',
          'adset_id',
          'impressions',
          'clicks',
          'cpm',
          'spend',
          'ctr',
          'page_name']
rawdata = list(AdAccount('act_number').get_insights(
  params=params,
  fields=fields,
))

# save the string as a csv file
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=fields)
for field in fields:
    df["{}".format(field)]=[x['{}'.format(field)] for x in rawdata]

#df.to_csv("insights.csv",index=False)
df.to_excel("insights.xlsx",index=False)
```

Here is my code. I am getting:

> UserWarning: insights does not allow field page_name

How to include this?

[image: facebook web browser insights].

If you have any question I am here.